# How to create a polar contour plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contourf

**Update:** I've done a full write-up of the way I found to do this on my blog at http://blog.rtwilson.com/producing-polar-contour-plots-with-matplotlib/ - you may want to check there first.

I'm trying to plot a polar contour plot in matplotlib. I've found various resources on the internet, (a) I can't seem to get my code to work and (b) many of the resources appear rather old, and I'm wondering if there is a better way now. For example, http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01953.html suggests that something may be done to improve things soon, and that was in 2006!

I'd love to be able to plot proper polar contour plots - like pcolor lets you do for its type of plot (see commented out section below), but I can't seem to find any way to do that, so I'm converting to cartesian co-ordinates first.

Anyway, I have the code that follows:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

azimuths = np.arange(0, 360, 10)
zeniths = np.arange(0, 70, 10)
values = []

for azimuth in azimuths:
  for zenith in zeniths:
    print "%i %i" % (azimuth, zenith)
    # Run some sort of model and get some output
    # We'll just use rand for this example
    values.append(rand())

theta = np.radians(azimuths)

values = np.array(values)
values = values.reshape(len(zeniths), len(azimuths))

# This (from http://old.nabble.com/2D-polar-surface-plot-td28896848.html)
# works fine
##############
# Create a polar axes
# ax = subplot(111, projection='polar')
# pcolor plot onto it
# c = ax.pcolor(theta, zeniths, values)
# show()

r, t = np.meshgrid(zeniths, azimuths)

x = r*np.cos(t)
y = r*np.sin(t)

contour(x, y, values)
```

When I run that I get an error `TypeError: Inputs x and y must be 1D or 2D.`. I'm not sure why I get this, as both x and y are 2D. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, it seems rather clunky to be putting my values returned from my model into a list and then reshaping it. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should just be able to use `ax.contour` or `ax.contourf` with polar plots just as you normally would...  You have a few bugs in your code, though.  You convert things to radians, but then use the values in degrees when you plot.  Also, you're passing in `r, theta` to contour when it expects `theta, r`.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#-- Generate Data -----------------------------------------
# Using linspace so that the endpoint of 360 is included...
azimuths = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, 20))
zeniths = np.arange(0, 70, 10)

r, theta = np.meshgrid(zeniths, azimuths)
values = np.random.random((azimuths.size, zeniths.size))

#-- Plot... ------------------------------------------------
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
ax.contourf(theta, r, values)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that's *very* helpful. I've pretty much got it working now! Just one quick query - if that's ok. I have to loop through the azimuths and zeniths to run my model and get out my data (the model involves calling another python library) - is the way I'm doing it with a list, and then reshaping the array, a sensible way to do it? Is there a more pythonic way?

Comment: There are several ways, but if you don't know the size of the array before-hand, then building a list and turning it into an array at the end is a very good solution.  There's also `numpy.fromiter`, which is nice if you're running into memory problems.  As far as the nested `for` loops, you could replace them with `itertools.product`, but that's largely a matter of taste.  If you could vectorize things to work with an array instead of a single value, you'd probably see a speedup. If you can't (due to the other library) then you can't, though.

Comment: It is often cleaner to write a simple generator (Most likely a function using `yield`, in your case) instead of a more "spagetti-string" solution, though.  Modular is better :)

Comment: How to deal with this ugly interpolation drop along theta=0 axis?

Comment: @JoeKington can I use the same approach for my question here - https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28058/calculating-curvature-from-height-contours

Comment: @JoeKington do you know a way to add a colorbar here? Unfortunately when I try `ax.colorbar()` I get the error `AttributeError: 'PolarAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'colorbar'`

Answer (score 4):

the shape of x, y and values must be the same. Your data shape is:

```
>>> x.shape, y.shape, values.shape
((36, 7), (36, 7), (7, 36))
```

so change contour(x, y, values) to contour(x, y, values.T).

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Do you have any ideas about the other parts of the question regarding the current best way to do polar contour plots in matplotlib?