# Is there an R package for interpolated polar contour plots

Tags: r, interpolation, contour, r-package, polar-coordinates

This [R interpolated polar contour plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856882/r-interpolated-polar-contour-plot) question is an excellent source for interpolated polar contour plots in R. Unfortunately, as explained in the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528999/fix-interpolated-polar-contour-plot-function-to-works-with-current-r-and-possib), the `PolarImageInterpolate` function in [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856882/r-interpolated-polar-contour-plot) has some bugs in it. My question is, is there a modified version of the function or a package or any other (ggpot?) way to do interpolated polar contour plots in R?

Here is a sample plot I made using the `PolarImageInterpolate` function. There are unusual values at the centre. It seems something is not right with the interpolation? Since `akima` interpolation does not allow NA`s in data, I removed them using  `complete.cases`. Is there a better option to manage NA's in interpolation?

```r
inp <- read_csv("test.csv")
inp <- inp[complete.cases(inp),]

y = inp$Height * cos(inp$Theta)
x = inp$Height * sin(inp$Theta)
z = inp$Value

PolarImageInterpolate(x, y, z, points = F)
```

[image: sample plot]

Data is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/79pe1kwjpa61qig/test.csv?dl=0)
Any help would be appreciated.