# Overlapping polar countourf and scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

Thanks to this very helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071084/polar-contour-plot-in-matplotlib-best-modern-way-to-do-it), I finally figured out how to make a polar filled-contour plot. However, when I moved to the next step and tried to add a scatter point to the same plot, I ran in some problems. Here is the original script:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#-- Generate Data -----------------------------------------
# Using linspace so that the endpoint of 360 is included...
azimuths = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, 20))
zeniths = np.arange(0, 70, 10)

r, theta = np.meshgrid(zeniths, azimuths)
values = np.random.random((azimuths.size, zeniths.size))

#-- Plot... ------------------------------------------------
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
ax.contourf(theta, r, values)

plt.show()
```

Which produced this image:
[image: Polar filled contour without scatter]

If I add also a scatter plot:

```py
#-- Plot... ------------------------------------------------
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
ax.contourf(theta, r, values)
ax.scatter(np.radians(140), 40, s=20, c='White')
```

I get instead this image:

[image: Polar filled contour with scatter]

Why do I get the thick white border between the filled contours and the axes? How do I get rid of it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ops, sorry the answer occurred to me two minutes after a asked my question. I just realized that adding a scatter plot somehow changes the axes limits. Forcing the axes to the desired interval fixes the problem.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
ax.contourf(theta, r, values)
ax.scatter([np.radians(140)], [40], s=20, c='White')
ax.set_rmax(60)
ax.set_rmin(0)
```

[image]

I thought I could leave the question on anyways, it still can be helpful to other users.

Comment: +1 What happens is that `ax.scatter` uses "loose" autoscaling (i.e. it chooses even-ish numbers as axes limits) while `ax.contourf` uses "tight" autoscaling (i.e. it strictly uses the data limits).  Instead of manually setting the limits, you could just call `ax.autoscale(False)` after calling `contourf` and before calling `scatter`.