# Gridspec of contour polar plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I have used the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416965/adding-a-colorbar-to-a-polar-contourf-multiplot) to generate the two polar contour plots that appear side by side. I can extend the grid to a 2 by 2 grid of polar contour plots by simply editing the answer to the above post such that you track the grid positions:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12,5),subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
p1 = axs[0,0].contourf(theta, r, Z1, 100)
p2 = axs[0,1].contourf(theta, r, Z2, 100)
p3 = axs[1,0].contourf(theta, r, Z2, 100)
p4 = axs[1,1].contourf(theta, r, Z2, 100)
```

This generates the following image:

[image]

The spacing between each subplot is clearly an issue. How can I edit the spacing both in the horizontal and vertical directions and scale each polar plot to make them slightly larger?

**MWE**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib import gridspec#, ticker


X = np.arange(0, 70, 10)
Y = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, 20))
r, theta = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

Z1 = np.random.random((azimuths.size, zeniths.size))
Z2 = np.random.random((azimuths.size, zeniths.size))
Z3 = np.random.random((azimuths.size, zeniths.size))
Z4 = np.random.random((azimuths.size, zeniths.size))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12,5),subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
p1 = axs[0,0].contourf(theta, r, Z1, 100)
p2 = axs[0,1].contourf(theta, r, Z2, 100)
p3 = axs[1,0].contourf(theta, r, Z2, 100)
p4 = axs[1,1].contourf(theta, r, Z2, 100)

#-- obtaining the colormap limits
vmin,vmax = p2.get_clim()
#-- Defining a normalised scale
cNorm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
#-- Creating a new axes at the right side
ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8])
#-- Plotting the colormap in the created axes
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax3, norm=cNorm)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05,right=0.85)
plt.show()
```

In the above MWE, I just added some example data that resembles closely the post in this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071084/polar-contour-plot-in-matplotlib-best-modern-way-to-do-it).

Comment: Make your figure narrower or use axes_grid

Comment: @JodyKlymak, could you provide a MWE on how to either option?

Comment: `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12,10), ...)` could be a start

Comment: I would except this is a duplicate of a question that is asked _very_ often.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475508/how-to-combine-gridspec-with-plt-subplots-to-eliminate-space-between-rows-of-s for a good discussion

Comment: @JodyKlymak, yes thanks for posting that link. Using `figsize` did the trick, but combining GridSpec with subplots was exactly what I was after.