# scatter polar plot contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am importing data from a excel file in order to make a scatter polar plot of the data. The data are all gather in a specific area of the polar axes and instead of having a concentration of points (cf image below, blue points and code below), I would rather have a the contour the whole group of point.

Is there a method to do it in Python ? I have tried to use the method 'contourf' (cf stackover flow: [Polar contour plot in matplotlib - best (modern) way to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071084/polar-contour-plot-in-matplotlib-best-modern-way-to-do-it)). But I am getting stuck into it, my attempts to apply it have failed. Is there another method to plot contour of a group of points ?

Thank you !

```
`
df = pd.read_excel('BW3/BW3StartValues.xlsx')
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')    
C = df.C
h = df.h
h = np.radians(h) # convert values of the angle from degrees to radians
ax1.scatter(h,C, s = 5, marker = 'o', color='b') 
ax1.set_rmax(60)
plt.show()
```

`
[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend you add the `matplotlib` tag to your post.  You're more likely to get the help you need that way.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you want. Do just want a 'coloured area' where the points are right now, i.e. a single-colour contour?

Comment: The points are all gather inside a 'rectangular' area. I would like to have a single-colour line contour that is the perimeter of this 'rectangular' area. I just had the idea to plot the points at the 4 corners of the 'rectangular' area and I would still have to figure out how to link with line the 4 corners so that I have a rectangular shape that delimits the area where the data points are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that calculates the convex hull of the data (I didn't know how the rectangle should be calculated) and displays that convex hull with help of a `PolyCollection`. As I don't have your data, I generated some random data points, but it should be easy enough to adapt.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')    

#generating some data:
C = np.random.rand(30)*15+40
h = np.random.rand(30)*15+290
h = np.radians(h) # convert values of the angle from degrees to radians

#following scipy example
points = np.concatenate([h,C]).reshape((2,30)).T
hull = ConvexHull(points)

ax1.scatter(h,C, s = 5, marker = 'o', color='b') 

#adding the convex hull to ax1 as a PolyCollection:
ax1.add_collection(PolyCollection(
    [points[hull.vertices,:]],
    edgecolors='r',
    facecolors='w',
    linewidths=2,
    zorder=-1,
    ))

ax1.set_rmax(60)

plt.show()
```

If you have the rectangle already calculated, you can just leave out the convex hull calculation and generate the `PolyCollection` from there. Note the `**kwargs` that I used to create the `PolyCollection`. Especially the `zorder` is important, as otherwise the polygon will be drawn on top of the points. The resulting figure looks like this:

[image: resulting plot of the shown code]

Hope this helps.